# Debugging with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to debug to test if my website that I am creating is working fine, but I am having problems. It directs to the following website rather than run my website. It used to work fine until today.

[image: Directs to this]

Below is what my MS Visual Studio looks like

[image: MS Visual Studio]

Comment: Looks like a virus/malware infection to me.

Comment: Also, why are you using a Windows Phone Emulator for a web site?

Comment: @leppie no that's annoying but it is disabled. Happens after you install Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: @leppie I dont use IE, it has always been there. I use Google Chrome.

Comment: @UmzzMo: So why the screenshot of IE?

Comment: @leppie because it was set as a default to use IE. I didn't know how to change it until now. If you can't help then don't be rude and waste my time.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the .aspx file in the Solution Explorer & Click "View in Browser". If the Webpage shows fine then the problem is with your browser.

To check if the problem is with your browser, change your default browser and the start the debugging.

OR simply IE has set your start page, to the one that loads again & again.

Comment: I did, but its still not working. it says "could not find localhost:57562"

Answer (score 0):

Did you install some of those dodgy toolbars today? Maybe NetAssistant? Your solution is to get rid of that stuff then it won't try and search when you're trying to debug.

Otherwise, if you're a real big fan of all those add ons and want to keep them, when you're debugging you'll have to run, then change the URL in the address bar to include the `http` protocol, therefore it won't search, something like:

```
http://localhost:57562/assignemcheck.aspx
```

Comment: Why is everyone after the tool bars? I use google chrome, IE was already installed the first time i bought my laptop. I have never used it and nor have i ever install any tool bars. I tried running in different web browsers and it still doesnt work. "could not find localhost:57562"

Comment: @UmzzMo Don't worry I was only kidding, sorry if I offended you :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing i can see is , you are not in Debugging mode, check tha Run button is still there, 
*i can see that in your visual studio image*

Run it properly, and try to go to just localhost or 127.0.0.1
if it show not loading or something like that, your ASP server is not up yet, try restarting, ..

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed  very strange. Try these steps and see if it helps.
1)Clean your solution
2)Click on notification tray on the toolbar(bottom right corner) and make sure that no instance of web server is running. if it is kill it.
3) right click on your webpage and click on "Browse With". Change browser to Firefox or Chrome and click "Set as Default". click OK.
4) Build and  Run your application again.